# Firebase Realtime Database not displayed when retriving to textviews in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

onCreate() method is never executed. I just want to take the below data to 4 TextViews. "Detail" is the model class.
No errors are shown when running the app.
view_temp is an activity.
[this is firebase realtime db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS8WF.png)

this is the **java** class

```
`public class view_temp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private view_temp viewTemp;
    public Detail detail;
    private TextView roomtemp, roomhuminity, bodypulse, bodytemp;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_temp);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("heat-stroke-device");

        roomtemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_room_temp);
        roomhuminity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_huminity_temp);
        bodypulse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_body_pulse);
        bodytemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_body_temp);

        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    detail = postSnapshot.getValue(Detail.class);

                    String rtemp = detail.getRoomtemp();
                    String rhumidity = detail.getRoomhumidity();
                    String bpulse = detail.getBodypulse();
                    String btemp = detail.getBodytemp();

                    roomtemp.setText(rtemp);
                    roomhuminity.setText(rhumidity);
                    bodypulse.setText(bpulse);
                    bodytemp.setText(btemp);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }


}`
```

Comment: Does this work? `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getReference("heat-stroke-device");`

Comment: Mentioned here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#get_a_databasereference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add the name of the project in the getReference() method. To get those names and the corresponding values correctly, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.getKey();
            double value = ds.getValue(Double.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name "/" + value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
RoomHumi/86.0
RoomTemp/30.8
bodyPulse/126.0
bodyTemp/29.0
```

If the keys are always fixed, then simply use:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        double roomHumi = dataSnapshot.child("RoomHumi").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "RoomHumi" "/" + valueroomHumi);
        double roomTemp = dataSnapshot.child("RoomTemp").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "RoomTemp" "/" + roomTemp);
        double bodyPulse = dataSnapshot.child("bodyPulse").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "bodyPulse" "/" + bodyPulse);
        double bodyTemp = dataSnapshot.child("bodyTemp").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", "bodyTemp" "/" + bodyTemp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

And you'll have the same result in the logcat.

Comment: isn't it goona be conflict with data type like `String rootHumi` but your asking for double data type

Comment: @Ashish Good catch, Ashish. Just updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: @AlexMamo It worked properly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your line

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("heat-stroke-device");
```

to

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Note: You do not need to put your database name into reference.